# Regexp. Sublime shield number in substitutions?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text 3.
I have big XML file with lines like this

```
<farm_plot id="260" x="29" y="8" input_fill="0" output_fill="0"/>
```

I need to set `input_fill="1"` and replace `output_fill="0"` to `extra_input="203001"`

Find what : `(<farm_plot .* input_fill=")(.)(".*)(output_fill="0")(.*)/>`

Replace with : `$1$3extra_input="203001"$5/>`

It replaces fine, but I can not set `input_fill="1"`. Because if I write :

Replace with : `$11$3extra_input="203001"$5/>`
it think, that I want $11. 

I can add space, but it looks ugly :

Replace with : `$1 1$3extra_input="203001"$5/>`

Result : `<farm_plot id="260" x="29" y="8" **input_fill=" 1"** extra_input="203001"/>`

Question : How can I write $1,1,$2 without spaces ?

Comment: you can use {$1} in your replace expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer is:

```
${1}1$3extra_input="203001"$5/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move some non-numeric data around to force separation of the 1's.

Find:
`(<farm_plot .* input_fill=)(".")(.*)(output_fill="0")(.*)/>`

Replace:
`$1"1"$3extra_input="203001"$5/>`

Comment: This variant adds interfering "" : `input_fill=""1""`